# How to exclude roles of nodes in path output

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph. Some nodes are role playing e.g. A node Leena would also have one more avatar AltLeena. There can be many avatars of Leena.

```
    create (jacob {Desc:"Jacob",level:"start"})
        ,(leena{Desc:"Leena"})
        ,(bob{Desc:"Bob",level:"end"})
        ,(brad{Desc:"Brad"})
        ,(jacob)-[:LIKES]->(leena)
        ,(leena)-[:LIKES]->(bob)
        ,(leena)-[:LIKES]->(brad)
        ,(jacob)-[:FRIENDS]->(brad)
        ,(kyle{Desc:"Kyle",level:"start"})
        ,(rick{Desc:"Rick"})
        ,(kyle)-[:LIKES]->(leena)
        ,(kyle)-[:LIKES]->(rick)
        ,(rick)-[:LIKES]->(brad)
        ,(rick_avatar{Desc:"AltRick",Type:"Avatar"})
        ,(leena_avatar{Desc:"AltLeena",Type:"Avatar"})
        ,(bill{Desc:"Bill"})
        ,(bill_avatar{Desc:"AltBill",Type:"Avatar"})
        ,(maya{Desc:"Maya",level:"end"})
        ,(kyle)-[:LIKES]->(rick_avatar)
        ,(rick_avatar)-[:LIKES]->(brad)
        ,(jacob)-[:LIKES]->(leena_avatar)
        ,(leena_avatar)-[:LIKES]->(brad)
        ,(brad)-[:LIKES]->(bill)
        ,(brad)-[:LIKES]->(bill_avatar)
        ,(bill)-[:LIKES]->(maya)
        ,(bill_avatar)-[:LIKES]->(maya);
```

This looks like
[image: Graph]

Now in the CQL, I'm trying to achieve paths between any 2 nodes as following

1. If start node and end node are not avatar, return paths which do not have avatar nodes
2. If any one of the start and end nodes is an avatar, return paths which do not have avatar nodes in-between

To solve this I introduced one more property Type:'Original' in non-avatar nodes and tried this query

```
match p=({level:'start'})-[:LIKES*1..2]->({Type:'Original'})-[:LIKES*1..2]->({level:'end'}) return p
```

But this is still returning me wrong results. Any solution? Or I'm taking a wrong approach?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is the [:LIKES*1..2] is matching nodes you don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the [:LIKES*1..2] is returning nodes you don't want, so they need to be filtered out like so:

```
match p=(b {level: "start"})-[r*1..4]-(e {level: "end"})
where all (var in nodes(p) where not exists(var.Type) or var = b or var  = e) 
return p
```

(A 1..4 range gets more results)

I think the *var = b or var = e* will allow the endpoints to be "avatar" type nodes.

```
var in nodes p
```

extracts the nodes from the path "p" and the WHERE NOT EXISTS() checks the nodes for the "Type" property *not* being there.

Comment: Wouldn't that exclude paths starting or ending at avatar nodes? My 2nd goal was -If any one of the start and end nodes is an avatar, return paths which do not have avatar nodes in-between

Comment: Quite true....you're basically looking for non-avatar nodes between the endpoints. Let me think a bit more ...